# meson not able to find include headers in yocto build system

Tags: cmake, yocto, meson-build

In yocto system, one of the packages uses CMake to export some headers as below:

```
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} FILES_MATCHING PATTERN *.h)

# headers
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN *.h)

# library
install(TARGETS ${LOCAL_MODULE}
        EXPORT ${LOCAL_EXPORT_TARGET}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# generate config
set(LOCAL_CMAKE_CONFIG_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${LOCAL_MODULE})
set(LOCAL_CONFIG_GEN_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated)

set(LOCAL_VERSION_CONFIG ${LOCAL_CONFIG_GEN_DIR}/${LOCAL_MODULE}ConfigVersion.cmake)
write_basic_package_version_file(
    ${LOCAL_VERSION_CONFIG}
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

set(LOCAL_EXPORT_DEPENDENCIES testcore)
set(LOCAL_PROJECT_CONFIG ${LOCAL_CONFIG_GEN_DIR}/${LOCAL_MODULE}Config.cmake)
configure_package_config_file(
    ${GLOBAL_CMAKE_DIR}/config.cmake.in ${LOCAL_PROJECT_CONFIG}
        INSTALL_DESTINATION ${LOCAL_CMAKE_CONFIG_INSTALL_DIR})

# install config
#   * <sysroot>/usr/lib/cmake/test/testTargets.cmake
install(EXPORT ${LOCAL_EXPORT_TARGET}
        NAMESPACE ${GLOBAL_NAMESPACE}::
        DESTINATION ${LOCAL_CMAKE_CONFIG_INSTALL_DIR})
# config
#   * <sysroot>/usr/lib/cmake/test/test.cmake
#   * <sysroot>/usr/lib/cmake/test/testVersion.cmake
install(FILES ${LOCAL_VERSION_CONFIG} ${LOCAL_PROJECT_CONFIG}
        DESTINATION ${LOCAL_CMAKE_CONFIG_INSTALL_DIR})
```

Other package uses meson.build system to find those exported headers.

```
dep_testcore = cpp.find_library('testcore', required: true)

t_deps = [
  dep_testcore
]

common_inc += [ include_directories('.'), include_directories(join_paths(meson.current_build_dir(), '../../../recipe-sysroot/usr/include/internal/'))]

testcommon = shared_library( 'testcommon', sources, include_directories: common_inc, dependencies: t_deps, link_args : t_link_args,install: true,)
```

However, currently this code uses hardcoded path to find those headers. How to get rid of those hardcoded path? Also, tried using `dependency(test)` to find those headers files but couldn't find it.

Comment: Add the required package name to the `DEPENDS` variable in the recipe of the package requiring it to make cmake find it automatically.

Comment: @skandigraun hardcoded path is in meson.build as shown in the question, need to get rid of that.

Comment: in yocto recipe you say that project A `DEPENDS` on B and then B will be installed (virtually) to the environment of A's build sysroot, where you can use meson's native way to find dependencies